# ContentDocument migration between orgs

Tags: contentdocument, migration-tool, migration

Is there any out of the box tool which can help or simplify migration of ContentDocuments to new environment?

- Custom object records are already migrated, external ids are used
- ContentDocumentLink is used to link Content to records
- Big amount of Content, around 100 GB

If not a tool, any suggestions/ideas how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We at iSyncSF have developed a 100% salesforce native tool to migrate data and files.
Our product is still under AppExchange review, but we are giving out free for community review.

I am sure this can certainly help you to move your data seamlessly.
Please contact us via: https://isyncsf.com/contact-us

Get more details about the product: https://isyncsf.com/product/